# Meteor application not working after configuring Nginx with SSL

Tags: node.js, meteor, nginx, passenger, lets-encrypt

I've deployed a Meteor application with Passenger integrated with Nginx(following [this documentation](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/deploy/meteor/ownserver/nginx/oss/xenial/deploy_app.html)). The application was running fine unless I configured Nginx for SSL with [Lets Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) following [this documentation](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04).

After applying SSL the visiting the application shows the welcome page of nginx with https.

I've tried:
removed `root /var/www/html;`, replaced `root <meteor directory>/bundle/programs/webserver;`

Can anybody tell how to point my domain to the deployed meteor application?

My `/etc/nginx/sites-enable/default` file looks like:

```
server {
    listen 80 ;
    listen [::]:80;

    # SSL configuration
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    server_name example.com;

    #return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;

    include snippets/ssl-example.com.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;


    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ /.well-known {
            allow all;
    }
}
```

And the `/etc/nginx/example.conf` looks like bellow:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    # Tell Nginx and Passenger where your app's 'public' directory is
    root /var/www/example/bundle/public;

    # Turn on Passenger
    passenger_enabled on;
    # Tell Passenger that your app is a Meteor app
    passenger_app_type node;
    passenger_startup_file main.js;

    # Tell your app where MongoDB is
    passenger_env_var MONGO_URL mongodb://<user>:<password@<host>:<port>/dbName;
    passenger_env_var ROOT_URL http://example.com;
}
```

Here is the  exact configuration of nginx (`nginx -T`)

```
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "example.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
# configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Phusion Passenger config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed passenger or passenger-enterprise
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/passenger.conf;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/mime.types:

types {
    text/html                             html htm shtml;
    text/css                              css;
    text/xml                              xml;
    image/gif                             gif;
    image/jpeg                            jpeg jpg;
    application/javascript                js;
    application/atom+xml                  atom;
    application/rss+xml                   rss;

    text/mathml                           mml;
    text/plain                            txt;
    text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor      jad;
    text/vnd.wap.wml                      wml;
    text/x-component                      htc;

    image/png                             png;
    image/tiff                            tif tiff;
    image/vnd.wap.wbmp                    wbmp;
    image/x-icon                          ico;
    image/x-jng                           jng;
    image/x-ms-bmp                        bmp;
    image/svg+xml                         svg svgz;
    image/webp                            webp;

    application/font-woff                 woff;
    application/java-archive              jar war ear;
    application/json                      json;
    application/mac-binhex40              hqx;
    application/msword                    doc;
    application/pdf                       pdf;
    application/postscript                ps eps ai;
    application/rtf                       rtf;
    application/vnd.apple.mpegurl         m3u8;
    application/vnd.ms-excel              xls;
    application/vnd.ms-fontobject         eot;
    application/vnd.ms-powerpoint         ppt;
    application/vnd.wap.wmlc              wmlc;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml  kml;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kmz      kmz;
    application/x-7z-compressed           7z;
    application/x-cocoa                   cco;
    application/x-java-archive-diff       jardiff;
    application/x-java-jnlp-file          jnlp;
    application/x-makeself                run;
    application/x-perl                    pl pm;
    application/x-pilot                   prc pdb;
    application/x-rar-compressed          rar;
    application/x-redhat-package-manager  rpm;
    application/x-sea                     sea;
    application/x-shockwave-flash         swf;
    application/x-stuffit                 sit;
    application/x-tcl                     tcl tk;
    application/x-x509-ca-cert            der pem crt;
    application/x-xpinstall               xpi;
    application/xhtml+xml                 xhtml;
    application/xspf+xml                  xspf;
    application/zip                       zip;

    application/octet-stream              bin exe dll;
    application/octet-stream              deb;
    application/octet-stream              dmg;
    application/octet-stream              iso img;
    application/octet-stream              msi msp msm;

    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document    docx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet          xlsx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation  pptx;

    audio/midi                            mid midi kar;
    audio/mpeg                            mp3;
    audio/ogg                             ogg;
    audio/x-m4a                           m4a;
    audio/x-realaudio                     ra;

    video/3gpp                            3gpp 3gp;
    video/mp2t                            ts;
    video/mp4                             mp4;
    video/mpeg                            mpeg mpg;
    video/quicktime                       mov;
    video/webm                            webm;
    video/x-flv                           flv;
    video/x-m4v                           m4v;
    video/x-mng                           mng;
    video/x-ms-asf                        asx asf;
    video/x-ms-wmv                        wmv;
    video/x-msvideo                       avi;
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/passenger.conf:
passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
passenger_ruby /usr/bin/passenger_free_ruby;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:
##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls
# http://wiki.nginx.org/QuickStart
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration
#
# Generally, you will want to move this file somewhere, and start with a clean
# file but keep this around for reference. Or just disable in sites-enabled.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

# Default server configuration
#
server {
    listen 80 ;
    listen [::]:80;

    # SSL configuration
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;


    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    #index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name example.com;

    #return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;

    include snippets/ssl-example.com.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;


    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ /.well-known {
            allow all;
    }
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/snippets/ssl-example.com.conf:
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/snippets/ssl-params.conf:
# from https://cipherli.st/
# and https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Strong_SSL_Security_On_nginx.html

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH";
ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_session_tickets off;
ssl_stapling on;
ssl_stapling_verify on;
resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=300s;
resolver_timeout 5s;
# Disable preloading HSTS for now.  You can use the commented out header line that includes
# the "preload" directive if you understand the implications.
#add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload";
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains";
add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;

ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;


# configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.conf:
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    # Tell Nginx and Passenger where your app's 'public' directory is
    root /var/www/example/bundle/public;

    # Turn on Passenger
    passenger_enabled on;
    # Tell Passenger that your app is a Meteor app
    passenger_app_type node;
    passenger_startup_file main.js;

    # Tell your app where MongoDB is
    passenger_env_var MONGO_URL connection_string;
    # Tell your app what its root URL is
    passenger_env_var ROOT_URL http://example.com;
    #passenger_env_var ROOT_URL http://www.example.com;
}
```

Comment: How is `example.conf` sourced? You appear to have added SSL support to the welcome page.

Comment: "How is `example.conf` sourced?" could you explain a bit more? I didn't get it.

Comment: How is it included into your `nginx.conf` file? My guess is that it isn't at the moment. Use: `nginx -T` to find out exactly what configuration `nginx` is using.

Comment: I've updated the  exact configuration of nginx (`nginx -T`). Could  you please check now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that one tutorial tells you to edit `default` and the other tutorial tells you to create `example.conf`.

In fact they are both referring to the same file, and what you call it is irrelevant.

At the moment you have you configuration split across two files, with two `server_name example.com;` which is confusing `nginx`.

Decide which filename to use, and remove the other one. Combine the passenger and Let's Encrypt configuration into one file.

For example:

```
server {
    listen 80 ;
    listen [::]:80;

    # SSL configuration
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    server_name example.com;

    include snippets/ssl-example.com.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    location ~ /.well-known {
        root /path/to/ssl/bits;
        allow all;
    }

    root /var/www/example/bundle/public;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Here in ```~ /.well-known``` block what is a "path to ssl bits" ?

Comment: @distalx The questioner was using two roots. One root is defined in the `server` block and another in the `location` block. The `root` in the location block needs to specify where the `.well-known` directory is located.

Comment: @richard-smith thank you for clearing this out for me.